# How to use over-ride the super class methods?

Tags: java

This was the question asked:

> Develop a class Decrypt that derives from FileInputStream and overrides the read() method of  FileInputStream such that overriding read method returns a decrypted integer.  Use this class to decrypt the file information that is contained out.txt.

I wrote a code for encryption, it worked but for decryption it doesn't. For decryption, i have to XOR the value with 128.
The problem is that after running the program, it doesn't write anything on the output file.

Here's the link for the sample input:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jb361cxmjc9yd8n/in.txt

This is how the sample output looks like:
How high he holds his haughty head.

The code is below:

```
//Decrypt class
import java.io.*;

public class Decrypt extends FileInputStream {
public Decrypt(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(name);
}

public int read() throws IOException {

    int value = super.read();
    int xor = value^128; // exclusive OR to decrypt
    return xor;

}
```

}

```
//main
import java.io.*;
public class LA4ex3b {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Decrypt de=null;
    FileOutputStream output=null;
    try
    {
        de = new Decrypt("C:/Users/user/workspace/LA4ex3a/in.txt");
        output = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/user/workspace/LA4ex3a /out.txt");
        int a;
        while ((a = de.read()) != -1)
        {
            output.write(a);
        }

    }
    finally
    {
        if (de!=null)
            de.close();
        if (output!=null)
            output.close();

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Is that space in C:/Users/user/workspace/LA4ex3a /out.txt supposed to be there? Your program most likely throws a IOException when you run it. Try to catch that.

Answer (score 2):

```
int value = super.read();
int xor = value^128; // exclusive OR to decrypt
return xor;
```

In the above you do not check for the special value of -1 returned from `super.read()`, which you must push through transparently. Without that you'll never receive -1 in your `while` loop and the program will not terminate normally. The code as below should fix that issue:

```
int value = super.read();
return value == -1? value : value^128;
```

Comment: so if i use if statement to check whether it is a -1, then how do i push through it transparently?

Comment: it still doesn't write anything on the output file.

Comment: just a small question, Is it possible to derive  Decrypt from  InputStream?

Comment: It is possible *technically*, but I doubt the result would be interesting to you. If you mean is it possible to mix in the decryption concern to any existing InputStream implementation, then the answer is Write a wrapper class (the Observer pattern).

Comment: was asking because InputStream is an abstract class and therefore we cannot instantiate an object of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should ask in your Overriden method, wether super.read() is -1, too. Because if super.read() is -1, and you xor it with 128, it will not be -1 any longer, so Decrypt.read() wont be -1.

Edit: Ok, I wasn't fast enough!

Answer (score 0):

Two quick corrections:

1. The output filename should not have a space in it
2. You listed no restrictions on data in your input file, so I suggest you use the "read data into a byte array" method (just in case a "-1" byte value is legitimate data in the input. Your particular text input is probably ok, but think of problems like these and solve the most inclusive problem you can still simply.

   byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1000];
   int bytesRead;

   bytesRead = de.read(dataBuffer);
   while (bytesRead != -1 ) [
     // decrypt each byte
     // write the decrypted bytes
     bytesRead = de.read(dataBuffer);
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
class Overload
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Int method with Two params executed");
        return a + b;

    }

    public int Add(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Int method with three params executed");
        return a + b + c;
    }

    public double Add(double a, double b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("double method with Two params executed");
        return a + b;
    }

}

//class Derived : Overload     //over riding//
//{
//    public int Add(int a, int b)
//    {
//        return a + b;
//    }
//}
```

}